# Wp e-commerce shipping problem

Tags: e-commerce

I am designing my first e commerce site with wp e-commerce. 
My problem is, that I installed the simple shipping plugin, ind I set on fix rate shipping.
After the I go to the front end, and buy something, click on the purhchase, and i see my cart, with the details. I can see the two options i set for fix rate. But the problem is that above the shipping options there is a sentence that wouldnt be there: "Please choose a country below to calculate your shipping costs". But I set fixed rate shipping so this sign wouldnt be there. How can i delete it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that ONLY fixed rate shipping is enabled, even if the others are not setup, if they are checked (in the shipping tab) then they will try to output.

Comment: Thank you, but other shipping otions is not checked. only the fixed rate ahipping. I dont know what is the problem.